# python3, minimum in nested list keeping index using enumerate

Tags: python, list, python-3.5, min, enumerate

```
nlist = [ [10, 6], [12,3], [13,1] ]
```

I am trying to find the list element with the smallest second subelement, i.e. I want to have [13, 1] returned - this I can achieve with:

```
min(nlist, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

If I also want the to get the index in nlist of the results by using the enumerate function I get cannot figure out to rewrite the lambda to open the enumerate object. This of course does not work:

```
min(enumerate(nlist), key = lambda x: x[1])
```

The expected result should be something like (index, min_element):

```
(2, [13, 1])
```

Perhaps this [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python?rq=1)
 has the solution embedded somewhere (not nested lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` returns a tuple containing the index and the element. You can apply the subscript operator (i.e., `[1]`) to it to retrieve the element and use it in your lambda:

```
min(enumerate(nlist), key = lambda x: x[1][1])
```

Comment: Ah - I was one obvious subscript away!